# How to get first id of dynamically generated div id with page load.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here I want to get first id of dynamically generated div id with page load. any one can help me how can I do this here is fiddle of other question.

here is HTML code

```
<div type="text" id="tag<%=count++%>" value="val1">ss</div>
<div type="text" id="tag<%=count++%>" value="val2"> ss</div>
<div type="text" id="tag<%=count++%>" value="val3"> ss</div>
```

here is JavaScript code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('div[id^="tag"]').on('click', function() {  
        alert($(this).attr('value'));
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to add relevant code here at SO. Don't try to cheat the system in place. you must have seen the warning message __Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code.__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for

[Updated JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5Y9mG/479/)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

 var firstElement = $('div[id^="tag"]').first();

 var firstElementID = $(firstElement).attr('id')

 $('div[id^="tag"]').on('click', function() {  
  alert($(this).attr('value'));
 });
 });
```

Comment: This is that, What I want, thanks for this. I am using this  `var firstElement = $('div[id^="tag"]').first().attr('value');
alert(firstElement);`

Comment: Your welcome, that works better just thought I would make it more easy to follow